# Custom cookie name for Claims based authentication

Tags: authentication, cookies, claims-based-identity, owin

I am using Claims based authentication and the IAuthenticationManager interface to sign in and sign out and so forth.  My question is this.  How do I give the cookie that is generated a custom name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CookieAuthenticationOptions that you pass into app.UseCookieAuthentication has a CookieName property.

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning: mine is in `App_Start/Startup.Auth.cs`. It may be common knowledge, but after seeing this answer, I was searching around where I was adding to the claim, upon log in (the wrong place).  Just don't want anyone else to waste time like I did.